# MsDeploy and PowerShell: getting 'Error: Unrecognized argument '"=Default Web Site/Folder"'. All arguments must begin with "-"'

Tags: powershell, webdeploy

I am attempting to use MsDeploy in an Azure DevOps release pipeline. Things were not going well, so I resorted to executing a PowerShell script line-by-line on my machine in order to troubleshoot. I narrowed it down to this one command:

```
& "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" `
    -source:package="C:\...\Web.zip" `
    -dest:auto,computerName='https://hostname:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Default+Web+Site,username=foo,password=foo,authtype=Basic,includeAcls=False' `
    -verb:sync `
    -disableLink:AppPoolExtension `
    -disableLink:ContentExtension `
    -disableLink:CertificateExtension `
    -setParam:"IIS Web Application Name"="Default Web Site\Folder" `
    -allowUntrusted `
    -enableRule:AppOffline `
    -enableRule:EncryptWebConfig
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Error: Unrecognized argument '"=Default Web Site\Folder"'. All arguments must begin with "-". 
> Error count: 1.

I am using:

- Microsoft (R) Web Deployment Command Line Tool (MSDeploy.exe) Version 7.1.3802.2153
- Windows 10
- PowerShell 5.1.19041.1320

This is the same error I am getting on our build server, which is running Windows Server 2019.

I've look at this command for hours now, and it feels like this should be a silly syntax error.

Other questions I viewed, but had no luck with the answers:

- [Running msdeploy.exe from within Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12993278/3092298)
- [How to run an EXE file in PowerShell with parameters with spaces and quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1673967/3092298)
- [How to use MsDeploy to deploy a sub-application within a website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12301578/3092298)

Comment: I think you're using the wrong syntax for `-setParam`. Try this instead `-setParam:name="IIS Web Application Name",value="Default Web Site\Folder"`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: I tried that syntax as well, and it gave me the same error. The most vexing part is, I copied this from a working PowerShell script. It makes me wonder how on Earth it was ever working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be something wonky about the `-setParam` argument, and how PowerShell parses these arguments. I ended up putting the `IIS Web Application Name` parameter in a parameter file:

```
& "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" `
    -source:package="C:\...\Web.zip" `
    -dest:auto,computerName='https://hostname:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Default+Web+Site,username=foo,password=foo,authtype=Basic,includeAcls=False' `
    -verb:sync `
    -disableLink:AppPoolExtension `
    -disableLink:ContentExtension `
    -disableLink:CertificateExtension `
    -setParamFile:C:\path\to\file.xml `
    -allowUntrusted `
    -enableRule:AppOffline `
    -enableRule:EncryptWebConfig
```

Changed the `-setParam:...` argument to `-setParamFile:C:\path\to\file.xml`, with the contents of the XML file being:

```
<parameters>
    <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="Default Web Site/Folder" />
</parameters>
```